# Sphinx search on RHEL / CentOS MySQL cluster

Tags: cluster, centos6, rhel6, sphinxsearch

Is it possible to add a new resource type to an RHEL or CentOS 6.x cluster, in order to allow Sphinx fulltext search to run alongside MySQL?

The clusters are managed using luci/ricci and cman.

Answer (score 0):

The trick appears to be to use the "Script" resource type in RHCS / CentOS Cluster, and run Sphinx `searchd` as an independent subtree, so that it can be restarted without relocating the whole set of cluster services.